# How to resolve a GET 404 (not found) error in MEAN application?

Tags: node.js, angular, express, angular2-routing, mean-stack

I'm currently trying to get user details (of the logged in user) on a profile page I'm building, but I receive this error:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/users/undefined 404 (Not Found)
error_handler.js:54 EXCEPTION: Response with status: 404 Not Found for 
URL: http://localhost:3000/users/undefined
```

I thought this could be an issue with stringifying the json data, but that doesn't seem to change anything, and I've read that Angular 2 no longer requires it.

I am using localhost:4200 for Angular, and localhost:3000 for Express.  When I do an api call on localhost:3000/users/id (with the object id), it returns the json data just fine.  I'm not sure what could be wrong.

Express route

```
router.get('/id', (req, res) => {
     console.log("getting a specific user");
     if(!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(req.params.id)) {
       return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Specified id is not valid' });
     }

     User.findById(req.params.id, (err, users) => {
       if (err) {
          return res.send(err);
        }

        return res.json(users);
      });


    });
```

Angular Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions, Response } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {

  BASE_URL: string = 'http://localhost:3000';

  constructor(
    private http: Http,
    private authService: AuthService

  ) { }

  get(id) {
  let headers = new Headers({ 'Authorization': 'JWT ' + this.authService.token });
  let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
  return this.http.get(`${this.BASE_URL}/users/${id}`, options)
    .map((res) => res.json());
}
```

Profile Component

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '.././services/auth.service';
import { UserService } from '.././services/user.service'
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-profile',
  templateUrl: './profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./profile.component.css'],
  providers: [UserService]
})
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {

  currentUser;

  isAuth: boolean;

  constructor(
    private session: AuthService,
    private router:  Router,
    private userService: UserService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute

  ) {


  this.session.isAuth
       .subscribe((isAuth: boolean) => {
       // user will be false if logged out
       // or user object if logged in.
         this.isAuth = isAuth;
       });
   if (this.session.token) {
     this.isAuth = true;
     console.log(this.session);
   } else {
     this.isAuth = false;
   }

  }




  ngOnInit() {

    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.getUserDetails(params['id']);
    });


  }

  getUserDetails(id) {
     this.userService.get(id)
       .subscribe((user) => {
         this.currentUser = user;
         console.log(this.currentUser);
       });
   }


  }
```

Answer (score 1):

please use the following codes:

Express route

```
router.get('/users/:id', (req, res) => {
console.log("getting a specific user");
 if(!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(req.params.id)) {
  return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Specified id is not valid' });
 }
 else {
 User.findById(req.params.id, (err, users) => {
 if (err) {
    return res.send(err);
 }
 else {
    return res.json(users);
 }
});
}
});
```

Angular Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions, Response } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {

BASE_URL: string = 'http://localhost:3000';

constructor(
 private http: Http,
 private authService: AuthService

) { }

get(id) {
let headers = new Headers({ 'Authorization': 'JWT ' + this.authService.token   });
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
return this.http.get(this.BASE_URL + '/users/' + id, options)
 .map((res) => res.json());
}
```

I hope, this works as per your need.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  Unfortunately I receive the same error.  :/

Comment: Are you getting this message "getting a specific user" in cmd ?

Comment: It's a 404 (not found) error.  My best guess at the moment is that I am not properly grabbing the ._id param in Angular, since it does work in the server.  But I don't receive any 'getting a specific user' message in cmd.

Comment: I discovered that I can retrieve the authenticated user data on my Angular 2 profile page if I manually put in the id into the url.  It looks like I need to pass in the id into my [routerLink] profile url.  But that's in my nav component.  Which means that (currently) my user info is not available for my nav component.  I know there's gotta be a better approach.